I can't understand what's wrong with my loop/asyncio when trying to run a telethon script
I can't understand what's wrong with my loop/asyncio when trying to run a telethon script
I've tried multiple approaches, but I constatly get errors when trying to run the client with asyncio - so with all functions running at the same time forever 24/7
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from telethon.tl.types import PeerUser, PeerChat, PeerChannel
import asyncio

API_ID = 'xyz'
API_HASH = 'xyz'
BOT_TOKEN = 'xyz'

# Create the bot client
bot = TelegramClient('bot_session', api_id=API_ID, api_hash=API_HASH).start(bot_token=BOT_TOKEN)

async def main():
        await bot.send_message('me', 'Using asyncio!')
        # and other functions of my own. i.e 
        # fetch_messages() etc 

asyncio.run(main())

raise RuntimeError('The asyncio event loop must not change after connection (see the FAQ for details)')

I don't want to make the post longer than it has to be so I'll skip all the other stuff I've tried because it failed :/
What I want to achieve is to have async def main() - and under them have all the other functions of mine I want to be runned asynchronously, and run them in a loop forever 24/7.
So far from what I've learned it should be done with asyncio.run(main()), and not client.run_forever or client.loop.something, but eh, none of them work for me anyway, so I have no idea what approach is the correct one
Full traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name123\PycharmProjects\TG_BOT\TG_BOT\main.py", line 55, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Users\name123\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\name123\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\name123\PycharmProjects\TG_BOT\TG_BOT\main.py", line 52, in main
    await bot.start()
  File "C:\Users\name123\PycharmProjects\TG_BOT\TG_BOT\.venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\auth.py", line 141, in _start
    me = await self.get_me()
  File "C:\Users\name123\PycharmProjects\TG_BOT\TG_BOT\.venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 165, in get_me
    me = (await self(
  File "C:\Users\name123\PycharmProjects\TG_BOT\TG_BOT\.venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 30, in __call__
    return await self._call(self._sender, request, ordered=ordered)
  File "C:\Users\name123\PycharmProjects\TG_BOT\TG_BOT\.venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 34, in _call
    raise RuntimeError('The asyncio event loop must not change after connection (see the FAQ for details)')
RuntimeError: The asyncio event loop must not change after connection (see the FAQ for details)
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0000029B76F2DC0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name123\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\name123\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
  File "C:\Users\name123\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 719, in call_soon
  File "C:\Users\name123\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 508, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-3' coro=<Connection._send_loop() running at C:\Users\name123\PycharmProjects\TG_BOT\TG_BOT\.venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\connection.py:322> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x0000029B92CD070>()]>>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-4' coro=<Connection._recv_loop() running at C:\Users\name123\PycharmProjects\TG_BOT\TG_BOT\.venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\connection.py:341> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x0000029B8AB1FD0>()]>>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-5' coro=<MTProtoSender._send_loop() running at C:\Users\name123\PycharmProjects\TG_BOT\TG_BOT\.venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\mtprotosender.py:464> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x0000029B92CD790>()]>>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-6' coro=<MTProtoSender._recv_loop() running at C:\Users\name123\PycharmProjects\TG_BOT\TG_BOT\.venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\mtprotosender.py:507> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x0000029B8AB1E80>()]>>
Unexpected exception in the send loop

RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <coroutine object Connection._send_loop at 0x0000029B84B2040>
RuntimeError: coroutine ignored GeneratorExit
Unhandled error while receiving data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name123\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\queues.py", line 163, in get
    await getter
GeneratorExit


we need to see the rest of the code

@ŁukaszKwieciński edited

Don't use asyncio.run() instead first get the current event loop by loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() then use, loop.run_until_complete(main()) also start your client first using bot.start() then call run_until_complete
Corrected Code:
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from telethon.tl.types import PeerUser, PeerChat, PeerChannel
import asyncio

API_ID = 'xyz'
API_HASH = 'xyz'
BOT_TOKEN = 'xyz'

# Create the bot client
bot = TelegramClient('bot_session', api_id=API_ID, api_hash=API_HASH).start(bot_token=BOT_TOKEN)

async def main():
    await bot.send_message('me', 'Using asyncio!')
    # and other functions of my own. i.e 
    # fetch_messages() etc 

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())


Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem, because I need it to run 24/7, with run_until_complete it executes script just once (and run_forever or run_until_disconnected can't be used with the loop. here I checked)

client.start() is using the default event loop on the main thread, but asyncio.run() creates a new one.
Move all client initialization inside the async def function, and then await client.start().

I've tried that as well before coming here with the issue (chatGPT recommended this option) but unfortunately it doesn't fix the issue :c
Here's the code I execute:
async def main():
await bot.start()
print("Bot started - success.")
asyncio.run(main())
The script indeed runs, but the console is empty - there should be a print statement, but there's none (other functionality I've setup like /help command on telegram that works with bot.run_until_disconnected - doesn't work when trying to run the script like that too)
